# Using CASE in PostgreSQL to SELECT different FROMs

Tags: postgresql

I'll try to create a query where the result can be from two different tables depending on the size of the first table.
Is something comparable even possible?

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(table1.column1) > 5
    THEN
        column1,
        column2,
        column3
        FROM table1
    ELSE
        column1,
        column2,
        column3
        FROM table2
    END
```

With this code I got something like this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 4:   column1,
```

Comment: Did you tried put selected columns inside a simple bracket? `SELECT 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(var1) > 5
    THEN
        (column1,
        column2,
        column3
        FROM table1)
    ELSE
       ( column1,
        column2,
        column3
        FROM table2)
    END`. I have not tried, it is a wild guess.

Comment: @Santhucool with brackets the error message slightly differs but it still doesn't work : `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 4:   FROM table1)`

Comment: What is `var1`? Is it a table column? If yes, from which table?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe in this specific case var1 = table1.column1

Comment: @Qvery did you tried sub query inside brackets I mean `select`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with c (c) as (select count(c1) from t)
select c1, c2, c3
from t
where (select c from c) > 5
union all
select c1, c2, c3
from r
where (select c from c) <= 5
```

The corresponding columns must be of the same type. Or be casted to the same type.

[WITH clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH)

[UNION clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)